# Issue with time zone in react native app using moment js

Tags: javascript, react-native, time, momentjs

I'm getting a 60-minute offset and I'm not sure why.

When I **create** a date, I get the following date:

```
Tue Feb 27 2018 11:30:28 GMT+0100
```

When I **retrieve** it from the database, I get the following date:

```
2018-02-27T11:30:28.000Z
```

I then **display** if with the following line of code:

```
moment(this.props.starttime).format('LT')
```

And get this in my view:

```
12:30
```

But I can see the value of the **moment object** being the following:

```
2018-02-27T11:30:28.000Z
```

Apparently, I have a 60 minutes offset from UTC time.

What's going on here? Because when the user select 11:30 in this case, it displays 12:30 in the view afterwards.

**Edit 1: This is how I send the dates to my database**

```
axios.post( `https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/api/book?starttime=${moment(this.props.starttime).format()}`)
```

**and this is how I save it in my database (Rails API)**

```
def create
  @request = Request.new(start_datetime: params[:starttime])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're losing the offset from UTC somewhere between creating the date and saving it in your database, and that your server uses UTC while your client system uses UTC+0100.

Exactly how do you create the date and then save it so that you can retrieve it later?

Comment: Just added these to my question. I manage to fix the issue adding ".utc" to my moment object but not sure if that's a good idea?

Comment: This: moment(this.props.starttime).format() ...looks like it should preserve the offset from UTC, so maybe it's a problem with how that string gets parsed by your server.

Comment: Ok let me look into this but could I use the .utc as a fix?

Comment: Yes, the important thing is that your client and server agree on the offset from UTC so that a time like 11:30:28 doesn't become ambiguous.